# Instance normalization and group normalization missing update

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, there is well-known batch normalization which adds the weights update ops to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`. But in the case of instance normalization there is no update op added. When using `tf.contrib.layer.batch_norm`, I can specify the `is_training` parameter which adds the update op to collection.
But for `tf.contrib.layer.instance_norm` and `tf.contrib.layer.group_norm` there is no such parameter, and also no op is added to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`.

Is this correct behaviour, or bug in tensorflow? How does the update op in instance normalization work then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should understand why does `batch_norm` need to add ops in `UPDATE_OPS`.

`tf.layers.batch_normalization` function will generate four variables, namely `gamma`, `beta`, `moving_mean` and `moving_variance`, and only `gamma`, `beta` are in `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`.

When it is in the training phase, `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` also need to be updated, so that if we set `training` parameter as 1 for `tf.layers.batch_normalization`, the function will add corresponding ops into `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` for updating `moving_mean` and `moving_variance`, whereas if we set `training` parameter as 0 for `tf.layers.batch_normalization`, the function will not do anything to `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`, since it doesn't need to update `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` in the test phase.

As for the `group_norm` and `instance_norm`, they only have `beta` and `gamma` variables, which have already been in the `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`, so that there is no need to add any ops in `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`.

Comment: But in paper instance normalisation also compute mean and variance https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.08022.pdf

Comment: But they also write "Differently from batch normalization, furthermore, the instance normalization layer is applied at test time as well." any clarification on this?